# MongoDB, trying to import json which has been serialized using TypeNameHandling.Objects

Tags: c#, mongodb, json.net

I'm receiving this error trying to import my json into mongodb.

2016-01-15T14:57:09.682-0800    error inserting documents: Document can't have $
 prefixed field names: $type

The json was serialized using Json.Net

```
 var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Comment: There are a lot of Mongo keywords that start with `$`. If you had a field name with a `$` prefix and tried to run a query in the mongo shell it would be ambiguous.

Comment: I noticed, I need the "$type": "ConcreteClass" within the json so that I can deserialize it back into C#.  Any way to tell mongo to force insert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names) which talks about restrictions on field names.

```
Field names cannot contain dots (i.e. .) or null characters, and they must 
not start with a dollar sign (i.e. $).
```

If you are using the Mongo shell to do the import you'll likely have to change `$type` to something else.

Alternately, you could use the C# driver to import the documents and it will handle serializing the concrete type name for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, will give it a try right now thanks!

Comment: I tried to insert C# object doing this but received a circular dependency error

`var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);
            await collection.InsertOneAsync(document);`